# Partial URL match for Jquery menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I have the following code in my menu but I am unsure of the best way to activate it on a partial URL match. Fore example:

domianname.com/users/ should be highlighted
domainname.com/users/profile/id/01/

I have put a PHP fix in place for now but was looking for a better way of doing it:

```
// check active menu
$SIDEBAR_MENU.find('a[href="' + CURRENT_URL + '"]').parent('li').addClass('current-page');

$SIDEBAR_MENU.find('a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == CURRENT_URL;
}).parent('li').addClass('current-page').parents('ul').slideDown(function() {
    setContentHeight();
}).parent().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the *Attribut Contains* selector [attribute*='value']:

```
$SIDEBAR_MENU.find('a[href*="' + CURRENT_URL + '"]').parent('li').addClass('current-page');
```

[jQuery Docs on *Attribute Contains* Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: I have tried that and rather strangely it does not seem to make any difference at all. I have even tried disabling the rest of the code on the page and it still does not add the class to the parent element.

Comment: I feel it is also worth noting the other pages continue to work fine.

Comment: Just putting this out there, but are you making the call inside of a ready statement? If the html has not loaded yet it won't be able to find them.

Comment: I just checked. No, it isn't.